# X has binomial distribution (n,p). Need to fond E(X|X>=1), v(X|X>=1). Compare with E(x), V(x).

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

[image]
I have found values, but I can not compare Var(X|X>=1) with Var(X). Can you check and help me, please?
E(X|X>=1)=np/(1-(1-p)^n)

Comment: $Var(X \mid X \ge 1) = E[X^2 \mid X \ge 1] - E[X \mid X \ge 1]^2$

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)